# MP4 'covr' atom - where is it located

Tags: mp4, mpeg-4

Where in an mp4 file is the `covr` atom located? Or where is its location specified, ISO 14496-1?

Answer (score 1):

It is typically located in `moov.udta.meta.ilst.covr`, see e.g. [this implementation of a cover-art-box locator](http://mp4v2.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/itmf/CoverArtBox.cpp).

The location or existence of the `covr` atom  is not specified by ISO14496 but a [non standard extension as explained by this project's wiki](https://code.google.com/p/php-reader/wiki/ISO14496#Non-Standard_Extensions).